# InfoPath form - The following location is not accessible, because it is in a different site collection

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have a site in test with Lists forms customised using InfoPath web forms. Environment is 2013.

When I try to open the forms after restoring in Production I get the error:

> The following location is not accessible, because it is in a different site collection: http://mycompany.com/sites/xyz/Lists/Template/SalesMaster/template.xsn.
>
> Click Try again to attempt to load the form again. If this error persists, contact the support team for the Web site.
>
> Click Close to exit this message.

The website url in the above is correct and it points to my List in production, I'm not sure why it says location is in different site.

I tried to publish the form using InfoPath Designer but it publishes fine still I get the above error in browser in my InfoPath view.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to publish to a different location and see if that works.

Comment: tried that already but didn't work

Comment: tried deactivating and activating these features but made no difference:

- IPFSSiteFeatures

- IPFSWebFeatures